# JSON response character encoding

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am trying to fetch JSON data in HTML with jQuery Ajax, i have some special character in JSON data so i have to remove special character, sample code.

```
$.getJSON("data.js", function (data) {
$.each(data.posts, function (i, data) {
    var div_data = "<div class='fixed'><div class='left' style='background-image:url(" + data.image + ")'></div><div class='right'><div class='box'>" + data.name + "" + data.title + "" + data.bio + "</div></div></div>";
    $(div_data).appendTo("#dataContainer");
});
```

Comment: What "special character"?  Why do you *have to* remove it?  Why can't the character just stay in the JSON?  Also, how are you making the JSON?  What have you done to try to solve this?

Comment: It is not JSON if it can't be parsed by JSON.  As @Mike Thomsen points out, you need to solve the problem server side by some form of encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a special character that's causing the JSON parsing to fail, that should be fixed server side. The alternative is you'll have to retrieve the JSON as a string, strip out the bad content and then manually run the JSON parser. If you have control over the server side that is definitely the easiest place to fix it.